# getPlayList() in YouTube API returning empty array

Tags: youtube-api

I have the following code, where I hoped to be able to console.log out the list of videos in the playlist:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");

        ytplayer.cuePlaylist({
            list:"PLf71xE2jRgTXB_LeUJkXxFwCc4r1z5if3"
        });
        console.log(ytplayer.getPlaylist());
}
```

But the getPlayList() method just returns an empty array.

When playing around with it if I call getPlaylist() from outside of this function it does return the correct array. Why is this method returning an empty array here? And how can I get the playlist array?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this problem myself. The issue seems to be a quirk with the player, and how YouTube (google) have defined "ready"

It seems that the onReady function of the player fires when the "chrome" for the player has finished rendering (i.e. it's tied the HTML document).  The actual player data (video or playlist) is loaded asynchronously, so is ready at some arbitrary point after.

I put a simple work-around in place that looks at the state-change event of the player

```
var firstLoad = true;
function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
  if (firstLoad && e.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
      //First Cued event - playlist is now available
      firstLoad = false
      myPlaylistFunction(player.getPlaylist());
  }
}
```