# onStateChange won't fire

Tags: javascript, youtube

I've been trying for a little while now to create an embedded YouTube player which will automatically start a playlist in shuffle when someone loads a page. A few searches led me to an alternative solution: Loading a new video with a random index in the playlist when the current one ends.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<button value="next" onclick="next();">Next</button>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }

    });
}
var oldNumber = 0;
var NewNumber = 0;

function newRandomNumber(min, max) {
    oldNumber = NewNumber;
    NewNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    if (NewNumber == oldNumber) {
        newRandomNumber(min, max);
    } else {
        return NewNumber;
    }
}


function onPlayerReady(event) {
    next();

}

function next() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
        'listType': 'playlist',
        'list': 'PLxBKLJmrCEphpgRihb-H0QUColR_bFu6s',
        'index': newRandomNumber(0, 139),
        'startSeconds': '0',
        'suggestedQuality': 'small'
    });
    player.setShuffle({
        'shufflePlaylist': true
    });
}


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0) {
    next();
}
}
</script>
```

With a bit of testing here and there it looks like this is the part which does not work correctly:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0) {
```

I've tried setting it to other integers and testing appropriately but it seems nothing will fire the event.

For what it's worth, the majority of the code was taken from here but I haven't been able to find any help on that page: [Shuffle Playlist fix for Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566131/shuffle-playlist-fix-for-youtube-api)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set the random and playlist parameters while instantiating the Youtube player, the shuffle and events works. Here is the code displaying a working player:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<button value="next" onclick="next();">Next</button>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        },
        playerVars: {
            'html5': 1,
            'listType': 'playlist',
            'list': 'PLxBKLJmrCEphpgRihb-H0QUColR_bFu6s',
            'index': newRandomNumber(0, 139),
            'startSeconds': '0',
            'autoplay': 1,
            'suggestedQuality': 'small'
          }

    });

}
var oldNumber = 0;
var NewNumber = 0;

function newRandomNumber(min, max) {
    oldNumber = NewNumber;
    NewNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    if (NewNumber == oldNumber) {
        newRandomNumber(min, max);
    } else {
        console.log(NewNumber);
        return NewNumber;
    }
}

function onPlayerReady(){
    //nothing to do as of now. 
}

function next() {
    console.log('next called');
    player.setShuffle({
        'shufflePlaylist': true
    });
}


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0) {
        next();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!